# Facebook: Objects always plural possible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-stream-story

I am creating a story for my users whenever they won chips on a table. In a standard scenario this is more than one, so the story will be something like "{name} won {title} in {application}" where {title} = "20 Chips".

Now apparently Facebook by default expects that my object will be singular. So Facebook will use sentences like "{name} won a chip in {application}", while for my usecase the accurate expression would be "{name} won chips in {application}". Is it possible to achieve this somehow?

Comment: You need to rethink your object naming scheme. It should be something like "prize" so that without a title it will be "<name> won a prize..." or "<name> won prizes...". Then with a title it will be "<name> won '20 chips' ..."

Comment: @user688518 yes thats what I considered, but I wanted to doublecheck first. Thanks